# Can i dynamically add reviewers to Gerrit based on the files changed in the change-set?

Tags: git, gerrit

I have a mechanism where I commit my changes locally and then run "git push..." to publish the change-set to Gerrit. Now, if i want to add a reviewer if there are specific files that have changed (as part of the change-set), I would like to add a reviewer. Is this possible ? Initial investigation points to git hooks as a possible solution, but it would help if someone could give a detailed workflow in order to achieve the above objective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by using the git pre-push hook. The steps are as follows:

1. Obtain the change-id of the commit that needs to be pushed to Gerrit.
2. Add logic to check if the commit does indeed have changes to files that need to be monitored.
3. Use the set-reviewers command to add the appropriate user/group as a reviewer to the particular review (using the change-id obtained earlier).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [reviewers plugin](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/plugins/reviewers/+/refs/heads/master/src/main/resources/Documentation/config.md), it can be configured to add reviewers based on standard Gerrit filter expressions, including file names. Pre-built plugin binaries are available [here](https://gerritcodereview-plugins.storage.googleapis.com/index.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer @sschuberth. I didn't need to use the reviewers plugin.

Comment: However, the drawback of your approach is that you need to install the hook on each client. With the plugin you have a solution that only needs to be installed once.